# Hibernate - Need to store data from table in tree structure

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table lets say "Profile" table in the following format:

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
A       A1      A3 
A       A1      A3
A       A1      A4
A       A1      A4 
A       A2      A5
A       A2      A5 
A       A2      A6 
A       A2      A6
```

What i need is, to read the date from the database and send it as a json to UI. but the information in json should be sent with parent child relation. for example

A will have two children, A1 and A2. Similarly, A1 will have A3 and A4 as its childs etc..

i need to show the date in the tree format. My question is , is there a way in hibernate to have it as a one object with list of A1 and A2 etc..basically nested arrays.

Comment: so to be clear you have one table which is mapped and you want to query that table but transform the result?

Comment: That is correct, i have one table with multiple columns. i would like to see the result of that in the Tree format. I am using Java and hibernate.

Comment: see if this helps:  http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/hibernate/hibernate-query-language/custom-result-transformer.html.  In transform tuple you will create your "row" object, then have a chance to transform the entire result set in "transformList"

Comment: unfortunately, thats not what i am looking for.